# The lambda function does not return value

Tags: python, function, lambda

The lambda function does not return the desired value to me
I sent **lambda x: x * 3.87** and I get ₪ 50
The problem is that x does not get the value 50 so lambda does not work
I would love to help how I get the value ₪ 193.50.

the problem is here `c('convert')(lambda x: x*3.87, '₪')`

```
def make_currency(val, sym):
    def dispatch(message):
        if message == 'get_value':
            def get_value(msg):
                if msg == 'amount':
                    return val
                elif msg == 'symbol':
                    return sym
            return get_value

        if message == 'set_value' or message == 'convert':
            def set_value(msg, value):
                nonlocal val
                nonlocal sym
                if msg == 'amount':
                    val = value
                elif msg == 'symbol'or message == 'convert':
                    sym = value

            return set_value

        return '{0}{1}'.format(sym,val)
    return dispatch

c = make_currency(10.50,'$')
print(c('get_value')('amount'))
print(c('get_value')('symbol'))
c('set_value')('amount',50)
print(c('get_value')('amount'))
print(c('str'))
c('convert')(lambda x: x*3.87, '₪')
print(c('str'))
```

**my output:**

10.5

$

50

$50

₪50

**output should be:**

10.5

$

50

$50

₪193.50

Comment: `lambda x: x*3.87` is not executed anywhere

Comment: Just a heads up that you should seriously consider looking at ``class``es. Selecting actions via messages corresponds to a ``class``' methods and storing values via closures/``nonlocal`` corresponds to a ``class``' attributes.

Comment: Either way, the ``msg`` of ``set_value`` is only used in the *comparison* against ``'amount'`` and ``'symbol'`` – why do you expect it to be *called* with the ``value``?

Comment: And how can I fix it

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a branch where you handle the `lambda`.

A `lambda` is just an anonymous one line function so you need to call it like you would any other function.

```
def make_currency(val, sym):
    def dispatch(message):
        if message == 'get_value':
            def get_value(msg):
                if msg == 'amount':
                    return val
                elif msg == 'symbol':
                    return sym
            return get_value

        if message == 'set_value' or message == 'convert':
            def set_value(msg, value):
                nonlocal val
                nonlocal sym
                if msg == 'amount':
                    val = value
                elif msg == 'symbol' or message == 'convert':
                    sym = value
                # this will handle the lambda assigned to msg
                if message == 'convert':
                    val = msg(val)

            return set_value

        return '{0}{1}'.format(sym,val)
    return dispatch

c = make_currency(10.50,'$')
print(c('get_value')('amount'))
print(c('get_value')('symbol'))
c('set_value')('amount',50)
print(c('get_value')('amount'))
print(c('str'))
c('convert')(lambda x: x*3.87, '₪')
print(c('str'))
```

That being said, you really should be using classes for this as most people would find the closures in this context extremely confusing.